# Triggering onclick event of Input/Form

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom

```
<form method="POST" onsubmit="return false;">
...
<input type="submit" name="button" value="Login" onclick="require('file.js').submitForm(this.form);">
...
</form>
```

How can i trigger onclick event of this INPUT element (so it can submit the form) in Internet Explorer 9 using javascript?
I tried:

```
document.getElementsByName("button")[0].click()
```

and

```
document.getElementsByName("button")[0].onclick()
```

but neither works.

(document.getElementsByName("button").length  = 1)

Comment: are you getting any errors? are you sure that this is the first button on the form? can you add an ID to the button and get the element by ID?

Comment: [fireEvent MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536423(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: No i didn't get any visible errors, but i know what was wrong - the form didn't submit if I left some fields blank. When i put correct values in fields it submitted correctly using click() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: The form didn't submit if I left some fields blank. When i put correct values in right fields it submitted correctly using above click() method. Thank you all for answers.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
document.getElementsByTagName("form").submit();
```

and for click event you can use this

```
element = document.getElementsByName("button")[0]
if (typeof element.onclick == "function") {
    element.onclick.apply(element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking beyond the surface of your question, I believe you're trying to trigger a form post AND handle the submission with some client-side logic.

The code you have prevents the form from being posted because of "return false;". When the button is clicked, it'll triggered the submit event, which is blocked. So how do you know that the button is triggered or not, knowing the results are the same?

For simpler coding logic, put the JavaScript call either in the form tag or the button but not both. My advice is to leave the button be. type="submit" means it will submit the form. The the form itself has a JavaScript function that decides whether to post or not.

```
<form method="POST" onsubmit="return prepost();">
...
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
function prepost(){

    // if the form needs to be stopped
    return false;


    // if the form needs to be posted
    return true;

}
</script>
```